# Professor nominated for award asks for a recommendation from a Dean, who is also on the Award Committee. Ok or No?

Tags: recommendation-letter, conflict-of-interest, awards

Is it conflict of interest when a faculty member who is a nominee for a university award competition, asks for a letter of recommendation from a Dean, who is also on the review committee that decides who gets the award?

Comment: Conflict for who, exactly?

Comment: I don't see a problem with asking for the letter.  The dean may end up having to recuse themself from considering that particular nomination with the committee, though.

Comment: This needs clarity. I've voted to close as I see no conflict issues at all, given what is written here. Can you clarify? I can neither answer nor evaluate any other answer as it is stated.

Comment: In particular, I don't think the faculty member has any conflict at all. That opinion might change with a more complete explanation of the context.

Comment: It is certainly a situation where a conflict may arise, so disclosure is a really good idea.

Comment: @JonCuster, who's conflict. Disclose it to who, exactly? Is a dean writing a LoR a fundamental conflict? Is serving on an awards committee? The relationships between the people are clear and public in both the committee and the letter. This seems to bind everyone from every proper action. The only time I can see a conflict is if the LoR is actually for the dean's job. Please, clarify.

Comment: @JonCuster, among other things, I don't see who here has conflicting interests; the student, the dean, the committee, other candidates for the award.

Comment: @Buffy The conflict is, nominally, between the interest in awarding the most deserving nominee and the interest in supporting a colleague.

Comment: @BryanKrause, but isn't _every_ committee member likely to be a colleague of at least one of those nominated? This suggests an impossible situation unless it is something like double blind review, which wouldn't work anyway since everybody's CV is different, unlike review of a single paper. People will have opinions about the relative merits of different things even not knowing the candidates. And most candidates would be obvious from their CVs in any case. You seem to imply that all awards committees are fundamentally conflicted.

Comment: @Buffy Yes, I think it would be very possible that everyone on the committee recuses themselves for one or more nominees. Each will be judged by the other, non-recused committee members. That's not the only way to do it of course but as you point out these conflicts are going to be very common so the committee almost certainly already has a policy they follow to handle them.

Comment: @BryanKrause, so, if more of the committee members know one of the candidates than is the case for others, that person gets _fewer_ votes due to recusal. Is that what you propose? This is an impossible situation. Ethics isn't a zero-sum game, I hope. Hidden conflicts are a problem, I admit, but nothing is hidden here. Everyone knows everyone else's relationship to everyone. People also, I assume, discuss things, not just vote. I don't, once again, see any conflict.

Comment: @Buffy Voting can be by other means than tallying; for example you might score each nominee on a range of factors and average the scores across raters.

Comment: I'd ask why the professor wants a letter from the Dean in the first place.  While there are certainly situations where the Dean may be a good choice, in most situations probably someone in the professor's own department can write a better informed letter (e.g., department head).

Answer (score 7):

It's probably the dean's *position as someone who could plausibly write a letter* for a nominee that makes them conflicted, rather than writing the letter itself or being asked to.

Normally committees like this have some way of managing these conflicts because they are common. That might include the dean abstaining from a vote or scoring system. It's also possible the committee expects nearly everyone nominated to involve some conflict on the committee and, particularly if the committee is large enough, their conflict may be considered too dilute to worry about as long as the relationship is professional (e.g., a dean or chair of a department has a professional relationship with any professors in their school/department) rather than personal (a spouse, sibling, etc).

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see any conflict at all. The dean has some informed opinion about the candidate and can express that consistently in both contexts. What conflict?

Comment: @Buffy Depending on the scope of the award, I think it's a conflict even if the relationship is just "they work for me"; they're not going to be evaluated impartially the way that nominees from other schools/colleges/departments are if it's someone they know personally who have to be evaluated purely on the submitted nomination materials. It's probably not appropriate to give the award to people who know the committee members best.

Comment: So, it has nothing to do with a LoR, but only with the fact that a dean is on an awards committee. Is that the issue? The asker/candidate is not a party to any conflict issues in any case. They didn't choose the awards committee and it is perfectly reasonable to ask a dean for a LoR.

Comment: Yes I started my answer by saying it's the relationship and not the letter that creates the conflict. It's not that the dean is on the awards committee but that someone on the awards committee capable of writing a recommendation letter for a nominee is not an impartial judge of that nomination. Like most other COI situations none of this means anyone did anything *wrong* it just means the conflict should be managed in some way.

Comment: It is even possible that the "committee" is composed entirely of deans and such.

Comment: @Buffy Sure, one possible way to handle that would be to have each nominee rated by the deans in other schools only. Or, alternatively, if everyone's dean is on the committee maybe it's considered that no one has an unfair advantage and each dean can speak on behalf of nominees in their school/department. That doesn't mean there's no conflict of interest, though, these are just different ways of viewing and managing that conflict.

Comment: @BryanKrause Conflict for "they work for me" isn't the last line of possible conflict.  What about "we are both in the same school", "we are both in the same university", "we come from the same city", "we come from the same state".... once you decide that a person is willing to act with a conflict of interest, there's not limit as to how petty the conflict of interest can be.

Comment: @BryanKrause Also, we have no idea what the process looks like in evaluating candidates.  It might involve having the recommendation be stripped of who provided it to simulate a "blind" evaluation of the candidates, it might include having the submissions edited to remove school names.  Without some insight into the process, it can't be decided if it can be abused, even with the Dean's recommendation.

Comment: @EdwinBuck I think a lot depends on the scope of the award. If it's "teacher of the year at the School of X at University Y", being in the same school is probably not disqualifying. If it's the highest award in a field, maybe being at the same university should be.

Answer (score 1):

Your question mixes up two separate issues. The first one is that deans are almost always going to want faculty working under them to win awards, because such an event is considered an achievement for the dean, not just for the faculty winning the award. So if a dean is involved in a decision of whether to give an award to faculty X from one of the departments that dean oversees, or to faculty Y from some other department, they have an incentive to prefer "their" person X regardless of their "honest"/objective opinion about the relative merits of X and Y's candidacy. This is a conflict of interest, and normally the conflict is avoided by having the dean recuse themselves from voting on the candidate working under them. The only situation where this rule won't apply is if it's an internal award the dean gives out which necessarily goes to one of the faculty members under their administrative purview. In that case there is no conflict, the dean will clearly just select the person they regard as the best candidate, and the fact that they gave an award to one of their faculty is not something the dean can brag about as an achievement.

The second issue is about the letter of recommendation. Here I would say that as long as the dean does not participate in the decision-making related to whether the faculty member who asks them for a letter gets the award — for example if they are recusing themselves from weighing in on your candidacy as discussed above — it is fine for them to write a letter of recommendation, and there is no conflict. The letter from them might come across as less credible however, since the other award committee members know the dean has a personal stake in whether the faculty member they are recommending wins the award.

In other words, asking your dean for a letter of recommendation is a bit like asking your mom for a letter of recommendation: your mom does not have a conflict of interest in recommending you, but people will likely treat what she says about you with some skepticism...

Comment: Hmmm, then why don't people have some skepticism when an advisor writes a LoR? I think the reasoning here is entirely flawed and doesn't take the "real world" into account. I know situations where a dean would absolutely NOT want a certain faculty member under them to win an award, though I doubt they'd have been nominated anyway. And if a dean doesn't vote "for" their candidate, they shouldn't vote at all, nor be part of any such committee as it disadvantages that person explicitly, giving more weight to other votes.

Comment: @Buffy As I think you pointed out somewhere else, it's possible the committee would be all deans. It's unlikely that the group of people qualified to judge such an award would have no potential conflicts with any nominee. It doesn't disadvantage anyone for them to recuse as long as others in the same situation also recuse.

Comment: @Buffy of course people do have considerable skepticism about advisor’s LORs for this exact reason. Such letters have some value since they provide useful context about a candidate that no other letter can give, but I’d say typically they are also pretty heavily discounted compared to other letters.

Comment: @Buffy good point that “always want” isn’t literally true, edited to take your comment into account.

Comment: @Buffy sorry but I don’t understand the rest of your criticism. _Someone_ has to be on the committee, and that someone may have a conflict so they shouldn’t vote when that happens. It’s pretty straightforward and standard in many types of decisions across academia (grant proposals, editorial review, awards etc). The “giving more weight to other votes” is a non-issue - you recuse yourself in case of a conflict precisely to give more weight to other votes who do not have a conflict, so I don’t see why you think that’s a problem.

Comment: _asking your dean for a letter of recommendation is a bit like asking your mom for a letter of recommendation_ - But asking your chair is a pretty standard thing, and they have similar incentives, no?

Comment: @Kimball it depends what the letter is for. If you ask your chair for a LOR for a job application, they have no incentive to exaggerate how good you are (potentially they have the opposite incentive, though that's usually not a concern). If you ask your chair for an LOR for an award, you're correct that they have a personal stake in the outcome since the nature of their job is such that your success to some extent counts as their success, similarly to the situation with the dean. For that reason, award nominations are more credible if they come from someone who is not your chair or dean.

Comment: @Kimball ... That being said, if the letter does a good job of explaining why you deserve an award, it will still count for something (even if it's written by your mom!). So it's still better to be nominated for an award by your chair than to not be nominated by anyone.

Comment: In our department, I think all our internal award nominations go through our chair and have a letter from our chair, though other people in the department prepare a lot of the materials.  But maybe this is not typical?

Comment: @Kimball when I was chair I wrote many letters nominating our faculty for awards, and a good number of those had positive outcomes. This is quite common of course. But I don’t see it as contradicting anything I’ve written here.

Answer (score -1):

Let me answer the question as stated and leave aside other considerations, which are important but don't actually affect the answer.

*The faculty member has no conflict of interest in asking the dean for a LoR **provided** they are qualified to write it.*

There is a separate issue, however, not asked, whether they are the best person to write such a letter. Letters should be from people who know you well and can confidently and honestly predict your success in whatever the position is that the letter addresses. This might be a dean or not.

It might even be foolish to ask the dean (or anyone else) for a letter thinking it would boost your chances for the award. I would recommend against that whether it is a conflict or not because it would probably be a transparent ploy that would likely backfire in both the letter and the award. I will neither characterize it or not as a conflict of interest, however. But dumb.

And asking someone to write only because they are prominent, but don't really know you and your work, is sub-optimal. You have better choices, I'd expect.

---

Whether others have conflicts isn't part of the question asked, though it has driven the comment stream here.